# Geo Push Notifications with Parse.com

Tags: geolocation, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I'm trying to implement geo push notifications using the Parse.com JavaScript API.

I need to send a a push notification in a near sphere of 1 km of a certain GeoPoint. My code is below:

```
Parse.initialize("<MyApplicationId>", "<MyParseRestAPIKey>");

            var ponto = new Parse.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);

            // Find users near a given location
            var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            userQuery.withinMiles("location", ponto, 1.0);

            // Find devices associated with these users
            var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
            pushQuery.matchesQuery('owner', userQuery);

            Parse.Push.send({
              where: pushQuery,
              data: {
                title: "Geolocalização Urba me",
                alert: "A partir de agora você vai receber muitas promoções"
              }
            }, {
              success: function() {
                alert("Notificação enviada com sucesso!");
              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert("Notificação não enviada!");
              }
            });
```

I always get the success message, but it doesn't work. In the Parse dashboard the campaing was created, but no push was sent.

What I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the javascript, but for the start i'll check what the first query fill fetch. Maybe the first returns no users. So after this line:

```
userQuery.withinMiles("location", ponto, 1.0);
```

insert this:

```
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " users.");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

This one should return at least 1 user, for the push notifications to work. Again, I dont know the javascript language well, I just want to help you.